# Not Printing a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

When I call the printBoard method it doesn't print anything. Could't find out what I wrote wrong
How could I fix that if the error is nowhere else.

```java
public class Board {
    private int rows;
    private int cols;
    private char[][] Board = new char[rows][cols];

    public Board(int row, int col) {
        rows = row;
        cols = col;

        for (int i = 0; i < Board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board[i].length; j++) {
                Board[i][j] = '-';
            }
        }
    }

    public void printBoard() {
        for (int i = 0; i < Board.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Board[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(Board[i][j]);
                System.out.print("|");
            }
            System.out.println(" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i would pay attention to how you are populating the array

Comment: I don't think that a class Board having an instance method called Board is a good thing. It might confuse the compiler.

Comment: Review the order that instance variables are initialized during the constructor invocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not recreate Board in the constructor when you set `rows` and `cols`, the array is initialized with default 0 values.

It should be:

```
public Board(int row, int col) {
    rows = row;
    cols = col;

    Board = new char[rows][cols]; // <-- reset array
                
    for (int i=0; i<Board.length ; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<Board[i].length; j++) {
             Board[i][j]='-';
        }
   }
}
```

You might have assumed that `Board` array would be initialized with the values set in the constructor, but in fact the constructor is invoked *after* initializing the instance variables in the order of their appearance in the class definition.